# Program to make "Pieslice" without using library function?

Tags: c++, vector-graphics

As we know in C/C++ there is "graphics.h" header file with the help of which we can do graphics programs in C. 
There is a function **pieslice** in that header file,its syntax is:

```
#include <graphics.h>

void pieslice(int x, int y, int stangle, int endangle, int radius);
```

[x,y are the center of the circle,stangle and endangle are the starting and end angles respectively]

Can we make a pieslice in C/C++ without using this in-built function.Please help. Tried making it with the help of the lines and arc function of the 
`graphics.h` but i am still not able to figure out how to connect the lines with the arc. 
Thank You in advance.

My code so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int gd=DETECT,gm;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm,NULL);
    int xc,yc,r,st_angle,ed_angle,StartX,StartY;
    printf("Enter the centers of pieslice:\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&xc,&yc);
    printf("Enter the radius:\n");
    scanf("%d",&r);
    printf("Enter the starting angle:\n");
    scanf("%d",&st_angle);
    printf("Enter the end angle:\n");
    scanf("%d",&ed_angle);

    double startRadians = (double)st_angle * M_PI /180.0;
    double endRadians = (double)ed_angle * M_PI /180.0;

    for(int k=0; k<startRadians;k++)
    {   
        startX = xc+ cos(startRadians) * r;
        startY = yc+ sin(startRadians) * r;
    }
    for(int l=o; l<endRadians; l++)
    {
        endX = xc+ cos(endRadians) * r;
        endY = yc+ sin(endRadians) * r;
    }
```

Comment: What do you already know about the pieslice shape that would help you draw it? Do you want to write a function that takes the same arguments as the existing pieslice function? To help people know what you're looking for, could you edit to explain what you are starting with? Do you want to construct this shape using arcs and straight lines provided by `graphics.h` or do you want to draw it one pixel at a time?

Comment: I want to draw it using arcs and line provided by ` graphics.h ` .

Comment: FYI: `graphics.h` is not a part of C++. It's some external library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sine and cosine functions to do this. Normally they start on the x axis and rotate counter-clockwise. The start point can be found by calculating:

```
startX = x + cos(startRadians) * radius;
startY = y + sin(startRadians) * radius;
```

Likewise the ending coordinates are:

```
endX = x + cos(endRadians) * radius;
endY = y + sin(endRadians) * radius;
```

Note that `sin()` and `cos()` take their parameters in radians. Given that `stangle` and `endangle` are integers, I'm guessing they're probably in degrees so you'll need to convert them by doing something like:

```
double startRadians = (double)stangle * M_PI / 180.0;
```

etc.

If you want to draw the entire pie wedge, you'll need to iterate from the start angle to the end angle and calculate every `n` degrees along the curve.

Comment: Please look into the codes i have written so far(updated my question). I know its not perfect,i am very new to coding. Specially usage of ` graphics.h `

Comment: It looks almost right. I think you only want one loop that goes from `startAngle` to `endAngle`. And of course you'll need to actually draw some lines between the points you generate.

Comment: Can you help me with that,please! I am clueless after this.

Comment: This site isn't for how to write code. I suggest you post it to the main StackOverflow site to get help with that.